# Session Variables disappear on AJAX script only

Tags: php, ajax, session, mysqli

I've encountered a really strange issue. I recently rewrote the code to update it from mySQL to mySQLi. I have a config file named 'config.php' making a connection to the database by both PDO and mySQLi as such:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXXX");
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX;charset=utf8', 'XXXX', 'XXXX');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Most of my other PHP scripts will use require_once 'config.php', and on those pages, I can view my session variables by doing a print_r($_SESSION), which returns me this array:

```
 Array ( [lastseen] => 1543419158 [lang] => en [username] => 1 [userid] => 1 [staff] => [mod] => [catchLegends] => 1 [special] => [dogs] => [trquest] => 1 [gold1] => [gold2] => [gold3] => )
```

However, ever since the update, my ajax file, which also calls upon the config file via require_once, when I try to view the session variables, it only gives me the following:

```
Array ( [lastseen] => 1543419470 [lang] => en )
```

I'm not sure what happened to the other fields of the array. Does anyone have a clue?

For reference, this ajax file is named 'map_ajax.php' and is called via 'map.php' as follows:

```
$.get('map_ajax.php?map=<?php echo $map; ?>&x='+x+'&y='+y+'&rnd='+z+'', function(result) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
.......(more code).....
}
```

Would appreciate any help as I'm absolutely new to ajax.

Session code in config.php:

```
@session_save_path("/tmp");
@session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['lastseen']) && (time() - $_SESSION['lastseen'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
} else {
    $_SESSION['lastseen'] = time();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $uid = (int) $_SESSION['userid'];
    $user = mysqli_fetch_object($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$uid}'"));

    // Check if they are banned
    if ($user->banned == 1 && $filename != 'logout.php') {
        header('Location: logout.php');
        die();
    }

    $time = $_SESSION['lastseen'];  
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `lastseen`='{$time}' WHERE `id`='{$uid}' LIMIT 1");
}
$allowed_lang = array('en', 'es', 'ph', 'lv');

if(isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed_lang) === true) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
} else if(isset($_SESSION['lang']) === false){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}

include 'lang/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';

define('GOT_CONFIG', true);
```

Comment: I don't see any session code.

Comment: why are there 2 different mysql connection apis?

Comment: The session code is written inside config.php - ill edit it in

Comment: When you set session variables remotely they are not available in the local page where you initiate the AJAX call until that page is reloaded (provided it also contains a call to `session_start()`).

Comment: The page contains a require_once on 'config.php', where the session_start() command is placed. I've added the part of the config.php code which calls the session.

Comment: There is nothing special about an ajax request; you treat it just like any other request on the server side. Are the variables / keys permanently erased or don't you see them only in `map_ajax.php`? And get rid of the `@` symbols before the session function calls as you do want to see the errors if there are any...

Comment: I dont see them when I do a print_r, calling $_SESSION['userid'] for example as gives me a blank. The strange thing is, I do not experience this issue on my offline wamp server. Alright i'll remove the @s.

Comment: Brilliant @jeroen; im getting these two warnings:    Warning: session_save_path(): Cannot change save path when headers already sent in /home4/emonex3/public_html/config.php on line 2

Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home4/emonex3/public_html/config.php on line 3                                         I'm sure this is the cause. But not sure how to fix them.

Comment: There you go, no session is started because something already sent output to the browser. What are the first lines of `/home4/emonex3/public_html/config.php` exactly?

Comment: This is the code in the first few lines:                     
 session_save_path("/tmp");
session_start();

//error_reporting(0);


//We log to the DataBase
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "X", "X", "X");
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=X;charset=utf8', 'X', 'X');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


if (!$mysqli) {
 include '_header.php';
 //if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin']==1) { echo mysql_error(); }
 include '_footer.php';
 die();
}

Comment: As a guess, perhaps you have some whitespace before the <?php tag which is being output to the client - the PHP engine would then think that output has been sent before setting the headers. This might be in map_ajax.php before you include the config.php, perhaps

Comment: Hmm, no white spaces currently exist in map_ajax.php (not that i can see in notepad++).  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause at last. Map_ajax.php was encoded in UTF-8-BOM instead of UTF-8. This has been resolved :')

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by enabling output buffering in php.ini.
However, I read that this isn't an optimal/recommended solution. However, I couldn't seem to find another way to solve this..... :(